# Как работать со строкой байтов?

Tags: c, строки, сокет, byte, printf

Есть строка байтов:

```
char* str = "\xa5\xa2\x00";
```

Как вывести её на экран?

Как вставить в неё байты. Чтобы получилась строка:

```
str = "\xff\xa5\xa2\x00";
```

и чтобы эту строку всё-также можно было послать в сокет?

Собственно нужно во время выполнения вставлять байты в строку и посылать её в сокет. Система Linux.

Comment: 1. Ответы на эти вопросы не сложно найти как в сети так и на даном сайте. 2. Вопрос содержит в себе два вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Это обычная строка символов. Только и того, что они записаны вот таким хитрым образом, в шестнадцатеричном виде через управляющие последовательности `\x`.

Вывести на экран? Просто `printf("%s\n",str)` или там `puts(str)`. Или вы хотите вывести ее в каком-то ином формате, не как символы? Тогда поясните, в каком.

Вставлять байты - нужно подготовить место достаточного размера для новой строки, и просто перекопировать в нее байты до места вставки, потом вставить нужное, потом - скопировать остатки...

Comment: @D-side А, пардон!